# cannot import name 'get_ipython' from 'IPython'

Tags: ipython

I use macOS and python3.7

I tried to run

```
from IPython import get_ipython
```

but saw

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_ipython' from 'IPython' (unknown location)
```

Can anyone share even a clue/hypothesis?

```
pip install ipython
```

shows that already I have ipython

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install --upgrade ipython
```

solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

my env can not update ipython,in conda env,you can try this command

```
conda update ipython==7.8.0
```

Comment: my env can not update ipython in pip's way,in conda env,you can try this command conda update ipython==7.8.0